# Getting more than the last few days from /home or stream table in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been working with the [home](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home) graph api as well as the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) fql table and I am hoping to get the last week or two of a user's news feed. So far using large limits (5000 which is the max) and timestamps to try and fetch posts from the last two weeks (using `until` and `since` for home and `created_time >` in the stream table), but I only ever get the last 2 or 3 days of news feed posts, around 200-300 posts.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a way to get a whole week? I realize that Facebook is going to limit the api and prevent apps from fetching years or even months of data, but 2-3 days doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I've waited a few days, it appears that I can still only get posts back to April 14th (this was as far back as I could go before), but the 14th is now a week ago and not 3 days ago. I believe that is was due to [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/525301577527928?browse=search_5174a5dabacf74b77690235) where some posts would cause the news feed api to return an error. I believe Facebook fixed the bug and put a limit in the api after their fix to prevent further issues.